# How to hide/ remove the ion-tabs in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

**How can i remove the ion-tabs once its loaded**

I am working on a chat application which is almost complete. The issue is that when i login to tabspage, then when i try to logout  and it takes to the login page, The bottom ion-tabs are still being showed in login page now.

How can i remove the ion-tabs once it loaded ?

I have searched the internet and didn't found any valid resolve to this problem. I really need solution to this fast. 
Following are some screeenshot to explain the situation, Thanks.

[Before login screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMSbt.png) 
[Dashboard with tabs page loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te45B.png) 
[AFTER LOGOUT (loginpage), still tabs are visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obczu.png)

Comment: you need to show [mcve]

Comment: are you trying to set the root to loginPage after you logout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the root of the tab, remember that each tab has its own navigation stack. By default, pages are cached and left in the DOM if they are navigated away from but still in the navigation stack (the exiting page on a push() for example). They are destroyed when removed from the navigation stack (on pop() or setRoot()). To set a full new root outside the tabs, do something like:

```
this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(Login);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks brother. It works perfectly